# Не загружается фото по url в VK API Python через attachment

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот

У меня есть уже загруженное фото которое я хотел бы прикрепить к отправки сообщения по средствам url. То есть сделать что-то вроде `messages.send('ПРИВЕТ', attachments=['photoUrl'])`. Но я не могу этого сделать, делаю все по доке но все равно фото не прикрепляется...

```py
self.vk_session.method('messages.send', {
    'user_id' : user_id, 
    'message' : text, 
    'random_id' : 0,
    'attachment': 'photo494414313_457254829'
})
```

При этом отправляется только текст...
Вот полная ссылка на фото:

```
https://vk.com/im?sel=-218278840&z=photo494414313_457254829%2Fmail697664
```

Вот ссылка на документацию https://vk.com/dev/messages.send этого метода

Comment: А если добавить `access_key`? Цитирую: _Если прикрепляется медиавложение, которое принадлежит другому пользователю, добавьте к формату описания медиавложения ключ доступа: `{type}{owner_id}_{media_id}_{access_key}`._

Comment: @mironovmeow, но в ссылке нету параметра `access_key`, если он нужен то откуда мне его узнать?

Comment: Нужно получить полную информацию по фото. Используете [_photos.get_](https://dev.vk.com/method/photos.get). Там должен быть `access_key`

Comment: @mironovmeow да вижу, но там необходим access_token, а тут уже попахивает JWT итд, этот токен постоянно обновляется. Поймите, мне просто нужен простой способ добавить картинку и все. А куча данных которые я не знаю откуда взять

Comment: `мне просто нужен простой способ добавить картинку` Есть два пути: 1) Получить информацию о фото через API (я не знаю, из альбома достать, например). 2) Загрузить фото от имени бота. Тогда access_key, вроде как, не понадобиться.

Comment: @mironovmeow сработало!!!! УРА!

Comment: @mironovmeow как отметить твои коменты как решение

Comment: Никак. Ты можешь сам создать ответ и отметить как решение. Мне рейтинг не так важен ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @mironovmeow,  за помощь!
В целом я делал все правильно, но необходимо было загружать фото от лица бота (группы) и уже после этого брать их url. А так же использовать url вот такого типа:

```py
"photo-owner_media"
"photo-218278840_457239261" # например
```

Url такого типа получается если загружать фото от лица группы